# What exactly does after tax "charge" mean?

Tags: accounting, insurance

My question isnt about the after tax part, but what is meant by "charge" as in "GE took a $6.2 billion after-tax charge".

I get that GE would like to get rid of their LTC (Long Term Care Insurance) business - take it off their books -- offload risk -- whatever. But when the word "charge" is used generally, what does that mean?

Sorry if this question is misplaced, but accounting doesn't yet exist in SE

Comment: A very good explanation https://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/one-time-charge.asp

Comment: This explains it well. Thank you. The quora article you posted was also good, did you delete it? So just to clarify in the case of GE, this is a non-cash charge? They're essentially declaring their entire LTC book of business an "impaired" asset, and devaluing this asset in a writedown by $6.2 billion. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right on all counts. (The other article was https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-to-take-a-charge-against-earnings )

Comment: Got it. Now how do I give you credit for answering?

Comment: I did not really answer it, I just pointed you to a public source of info.

Comment: I have the answer because of you

Answer (score 1):

The after-tax charge will most likely be a one-off charge of which the after-tax value is $6.2b, for example through an impairment.